# Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a simple todo app with `flask` and `sqlalchemy`.

I have the code below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHERMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/umutcan/Desktop/pythonProject/To-Do app/todo.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class ToDo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this output:

```
PS C:\Users\umutcan\Desktop\pythonProject\To-Do app> & C:/Anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/umutcan/Desktop/pythonProject/To-Do app/todo.py"
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
 * Serving Flask app "todo" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 240-804-640
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

What can I do in order to solve it?

Comment: I see you got downvoted. I just improved your question so it is more readable but in order to avoid this happening on your next questions you should read a bit more on how to ask questions and format them. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app seems to be running as it should. You just have to set the variables in order to make `flask-sqlalchemy` work.

You have mispelled `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`. So your code would actually be:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/umutcan/Desktop/pythonProject/To-Do app/todo.db'
```

To disable warnings about `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` you have to set it to `False`:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```